# Reindexing not working through SSH

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, indexing, reindex

I tried to reindex using SSH. Here is one of the commands I used -

```
php -f indexer.php --reindexall
```

and here is the result which i am getting -

```
Usage:  php -f indexer.php -- [options]

  --status <indexer>            Show Indexer(s) Status
  --mode <indexer>              Show Indexer(s) Index Mode
  --mode-realtime <indexer>     Set index mode type "Update on Save"
  --mode-manual <indexer>       Set index mode type "Manual Update"
  --reindex <indexer>           Reindex Data
  info                          Show allowed indexers
  reindexall                    Reindex Data by all indexers
  help
```

Comment: where do you execute this command from?

Comment: from the shell folder in magento root

Comment: then it must be something of your environment, what is the server's OS?

Comment: CentOS I came to magento root and this worked now: php -f indexer.php --reindexall

Comment: so your indexer.php in in MAGENTO_ROOT??? this is not where it is supposed to be

Comment: what version are you using?

Comment: sorry php -f shell/indexer.php --reindexall  worked. It is strange as in shell php -f indexer.php --reindexall  did not work

Comment: feel free to undo your downvote now.

Comment: I tried , it says i cannot unless answer is edited :)

Comment: I've just edited it now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27466/discussion-between-tasawer-khan-and-osdave).

Answer (score 4):

The `reindexall` command is without the `--`.

So `php -f indexer.php reindexall` should work!

Answer (score 0):

Connect your Magento store with SSH and use cd command to go to MAGENTO_ROOT/shell.

Now run the following commands on by one:

```
php indexer.php help

php indexer.php --status

php indexer.php info

php indexer.php --reindexall
```

Answer (score 0):

```
php -f shell/indexer.php reindexall
```

OR

```
php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_product_attribute
php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_product_price
php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_url
php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_product_flat
php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_category_flat
php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_category_product
php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalogsearch_fulltext
php shell/indexer.php --reindex cataloginventory_stock
```